# Understanding Results of Weka SVM Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm

The output of the Weka SVM classifier is something like:

```
-1.8471 (normalized) Feature A
-1.6281 (normalized) Feature B
-1.616  (normalized) Feature C
...
1.2765  (normalized) Feature D
1.3356  (normalized) Feature E
1.3402  (normalized) Feature F
```

How do I interpret these results? The class index is "Right" or "Left" (handedness)